# stroke-dasharray to visual data without libraries

Tags: javascript

I am trying to animate `stroke-dasharray` of a svg circle based on data values without using libraries.

Data is coming from a javascript calculation, so length of stroke will be different from circle to another.

code will as following: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/KareemAtif/pen/merEdB)

or

```js
var circle_1 = 20,
    circle_2 = 33,
    circle_3 = 42;
document.getElementById('circle_1').innerHTML = circle_1;
document.getElementById('circle_2').innerHTML = circle_2;
document.getElementById('circle_3').innerHTML = circle_3;
```

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 100px 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
circle {
  stroke: #222;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-width: 3px
}
.result {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <li>
    <svg width="100" height="100">
      <circle cy="50" cx="50" r="40" stroke-dasharray="0em" stroke-dashoffset="0" />
    </svg>
    <div class="result" id="circle_1"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <svg width="100" height="100">
      <circle cy="50" cx="50" r="40" stroke-dasharray="0em" stroke-dashoffset="0" />
    </svg>
    <div class="result" id="circle_2"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <svg width="100" height="100">
      <circle cy="50" cx="50" r="40" stroke-dasharray="0em" stroke-dashoffset="0" />
    </svg>
    <div class="result" id="circle_3"></div>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: That I can't make the stroke animate to return the value of circle

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want a pie chart using SVG circle and no library. I worked on something like that recently, here is a mixin I made:

http://codepen.io/Draccoz/pen/GJVJVM

```
=pie-chart($size, $ring-size, $ring-color: false, $bg-size: 0, $bg-color: transparent)
  $d: $size - $ring-size

  width: $size
  height: $size
  >
  circle
    cx: $size / 2
    cy: $size / 2

    &:nth-child(1)
      r: $bg-size / 2
      @if $bg-color
        fill: $bg-color

    &:nth-child(2)
      font-size: $d * 1.01 * $PI
      stroke-width: $ring-size
      r: $d / 2
      fill: transparent
      @if $ring-color
        stroke: $ring-color
      /* stroke-linecap: round */
      transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s ease-in-out
      transform: translateY($size) rotate(-90deg)
      stroke-dasharray: 1em 1em
      stroke-dashoffset: 0
      @content
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's exactly how I want it, except it is not as simple as I expected :)

Comment: Well, I made it a bit "universal", so the basic version would be simpler. The important part of it is `font-size: $d * 1.01 * $PI`, `stroke-dasharray: 1em 1em` and `stroke-dashoffset: 0` and then change the dashoffset as fraction of **not covered** ring (0 - 100%, 1 - 0%). The rest is styling etc. To make it animate you only have to add `transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s` and you're done!